# Output a negative MySQL Time value with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I've already spent hours at the same problem:
I stored some values in my MySQL database, the field type is TIME.
Usually I output my time-values like this

```
echo date("H:i",strtotime($time))
```

Usually this works fine but now there are some problems with negative values and zero values as an example:

```
 04:12:00 -> will output 04:12 -> fine
-08:18:00 -> will output 01:00 -> why?
 00:00:00 -> will output 01:00 -> why?
```

Comment: To work with date and time in PHP, try using `date_create` and `date_format` instead. It gives you more flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Time !== Duration` There is no such thing as a negative time.... when was the last time you set your alarm clock for -2am? A negative time is probably being treated as `00:00`

As for why `00:00:00` gives `01:00`, then I'd suspect that the strtotime() is defaulting to the unix timestamp base time (00:00:00 UTC Thursday 1, January 1970), and that your timezone setting is +1:00 hours

If you want to work with durations in PHP, look at DateTime objects and at [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

Comment: Thank you very much this makes sense :-)! So as an example you would recommend to calculate the duration between two timestamps in seconds an then store them into a INTEGER field?

Comment: That would be a more sensible approach, yes; or actually store an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) duration as a string